# Access model from acceptance test

Tags: ember.js

How do I access the current model?  I am aware of `application.__container_.lookup` but I understand this is a bit of a hack.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import { module, test } from 'qunit';
import startApp from 'myapp/tests/helpers/start-app';

let application;

module('Acceptance | booking/edit', {
  beforeEach: function() {
    application = startApp();
  },

  afterEach: function() {
    Ember.run(application, 'destroy');
  }
});

test('visiting /booking/edit', function(assert) {
  visit('/booking/1');

  //At this point I would like to access the model returned from the route model hook.

  andThen(function() {
    assert.equal(currentURL(), '/booking/1');
  });
});
```

Sample Route excerpt.

```
  this.route('booking', { path:'/booking' }, function() {
    this.route('edit', { path:'/:booking_id' }, function() {
      this.route('account', { path:'/account' });

      ...
    });

   ...
  });
```

Comment: when you say "the current model" are you asking about the model you return from the route for "/booking/1" ? Are you using a cache/identity map of some kind like ember-data or is this all ajax driven? What does your route look like today?

Comment: I mean the model returned by the model hook in a route as you correctly stated.  I am using ember-data.  I will post the route.

Comment: What information do you need from the model?

Comment: @Kitler, I am verifying that when a typeahead.js search is selected, it appropriately updates the model.  So I want to do something like `assert.equal(model.get('account.name'), 'Qunit', 'names should match')'`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `moduleFor` and then within the test you can use `this.subject()` to access the controller.

`moduleFor('controller:bookingsEdit', 'Bookings Edit Controller');`

If `moduleFor` is undefined. Then import moduleFor  `import {moduleFor} from 'ember-qunit';`
and then within the test you can use `this.subject()` to access the controller

> moduleFor(fullName [, description [, callbacks]])
>
> fullName: (String) - The full name of the unit, ie
>   controller:application, route:index.
>
> description: (String) optional - The description of the module
>
> callbacks: (Object) optional - Normal QUnit callbacks (setup and
>   teardown), with addition to needs, which allows you specify the other
>   units the tests will need.

http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/testing/testing-controllers/

https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-qunit

Comment: For the records: This is deprecated now, see https://github.com/emberjs/ember-qunit/blob/master/docs/migration.md